# Add window name to screenshot - bash command execution in key shortcut

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-16.04, screenshot, zsh

**Following command works fine:**

```
scrot  "%Y%m%d_%H%M_%S_""${$(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname)%%:*}"".png" -muz
```

But if I put it in as shortcut it creates a file which ignores the inner commands:

```
20190530_1711_50_{(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname)%:*}.png
```

[image]

I tried it as function in ***.bashrc*** / ***.zshrc*** (tried both) without positive results.

How to get it working?

Comment: Where (and how) did you put it in as a shortcut? And why have you tagged this both bash and zsh?

Comment: print your desktop shortcut file. Remember shortcut file can have only 1 argument from the selected file. And better not have any argument. Better create utility bash script (with 0 arguments) and pass it to the shortcut file.

Comment: @DudiBoy could you show your solution in code? I cannot follow your instructions if my aim is to get the window title into the file name (with scrot or any other application but as said - as shortcut with "auto" file storage).

Comment: A desktop shortcut is not a bash script, and is not interpreting variables. And the format of desktop shortcut file differ by the desktop environments. Please provide sample desktop shortcut file.

Comment: Again, i cannot follow where your comment wants to lead me. Could you please write a solution with your ideas as code? I guest if the shortcut env knows scrot it should know other env variables as well, no?

Comment: @jww why do you thing this question about process automation is not a programming and development question?